# Don't Overwrite Files Downloaded Throught Livestreamer

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm downloading multiple video files via Livestreamer. Sometimes it fails to download some files because of timeout. So, I start the script again. Script is a `.BAT` file. Livestreamer API asks every single time about `filename.ext already exist. Do you want to overwrite it? [Y/N]`. So, how can I put automatically `N`?

Comment: `echo N|your_command.exe`?

Comment: Solved. Thanks :)